# How to get length value of ng-maxlength in ng-message

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

In a message of ng-message, how do I get the value entered in the ng-maxlength?
For example:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text"
           name="myName"
           ng-model="name"
           ng-maxlength="5"/>

  <div ng-messages="myForm.myName.$error" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="maxlength">Please enter up to {{??}} characters</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: have a variable for the maxlength

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a variable so you can reuse it

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text"
           name="myName"
           ng-model="name"
           ng-minlength="nameConstraint.maxlength"/>

  <div ng-messages="myForm.myName.$error" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="maxlength">Please enter up to {{nameConstraint.maxlength}} characters</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

There is no other way around, maxLength directive watch the attribute maxlength and use the $validators to validate the length.

Here is the maxlength's code directive in angular :

```
var maxlengthDirective = function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
      if (!ctrl) return;
      var maxlength = -1;
      attr.$observe('maxlength', function(value) {
        var intVal = toInt(value);
        maxlength = isNaN(intVal) ? -1 : intVal;
        ctrl.$validate();
      });
      ctrl.$validators.maxlength = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        return (maxlength < 0) || ctrl.$isEmpty(viewValue) || (viewValue.length <= maxlength);
      };
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use this

```
<div  ng-messages="myForm.myName.$error" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
  <div ng-if="name.length <= 5" >
     Please enter up to {{name.length}} characters 
  </div>
 </div>
```